# Error async with openai and flask_socketio

Tags: flask, flask-socketio, azure-openai

i am writing flask and openai application. But when combining stream and flask_socketio I get an error when I for through the returned stream results, it is not directly returning to the client instead it is sending a series of results at once.

@socketio.on("chat", namespace=namespace)
def company_chat(data: list):

```
print(f"I'm in function: {inspect.currentframe().f_code.co_name}")
try:
    request_json = RequestCompanyChat(**data)
    results = company_research.get_company_chat(
        request_json.locale, request_json.company_name, 
     request_json.messages
    )
    for chunk in results:
        content = chunk.choices[0].delta.content or ""
        socketio.send(
        ResponseCompanySearch(content=content).model_dump_json(),
            namespace=namespace,
            to=request.sid,
        )
        print(chunk.choices[0].delta.content or "", end="")
    socketio.send("end", namespace=namespace, to=request.sid)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    import traceback
    traceback.print_exc()
    socketio.send("An error occurred: " + str(e), namespace=namespace)
```

I have tried many ways with asynchronous but without success looking forward to receiving support.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: You are not showing enough code. My guess is that the implementation of the iterator you have in `results` is incorrect.